# Drupal multiple ajax calls to a custom module

Tags: php, ajax, module, drupal-7

I have the following code in my custommodule_menu right now there is one ajax call to it. I want to add another and consequently create a new function (a new page callback) to handle it, how would i do this.

```
function a_b_menu() {
   $items['/a_b/email/%'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'a_b_ajax_email',
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'page arguments' => array(1),
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      'access callback' => TRUE,

   );
   return $items;
}
```

Comment: Do you want a 2nd page setting up to handle a different Ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do the following:

```
$items['/a_b/email/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'a_b_ajax_email',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,

);

$items['/a_b/new_page/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'a_b_ajax_new_page',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,

);
```

Then since no file key is defined in the menus $items array for where the methods are stored, find a_b_ajax_email method in the same file and copy/paste this and rename to a_b_ajax_new_page.
Then go ahead and change the functionality to suit your needs.